# How to access result of sql query and use it in other sql query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am retrieving "formID" here in below PHP code

```
 <?php

       header('Content-type=application/json;charset=utf-8');

       include("connection.php");
       session_start();

       if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

         $event_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['event_date']);

         $event_location = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['event_location']); 

         $organisation_name= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['organisation_name']); 




         $query = "SELECT * FROM feedbackform_db WHERE event_date = '$event_date' and event_location = '$event_location' and organisation_name = '$organisation_name'";

        $response=mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($response);


        if($rows == 0) { 
          $data['welcome'] = "unsucessful";
         }
         else  {
             $row = mysqli_fetch_row($response);
             $array = array(
                array(

                    "formID"=>$row[0],


                )
            );
             $data['welcome'] = "successful";
             $data['details'] = $array;
             $data['success'] = 1;
             $data['message']="successful";
             }
            echo json_encode($data);

    }
    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

I want to run one more INSERT sql query in the same PHP code ,where I want to insert the same formID in some other database table
How can I do it?

Comment: Try the first thing that comes to mind. I bet it will work.

Comment: Did my answer help you ?

Answer (score 0):

To be run after the `SELECT` query.

```php
$insertStr = "INSERT INTO othertable (someCol, rowId) VALUES (1, $row[0])";

$insertQry = mysqli_query($con, $insertStr);

if ($insertQry) {
    // What to do if the insert was successful
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use this method to tell to mysql return results as array, please check http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

```
$array = [];
while ($row = $result->mysqli_fetch_assoc()) { //Iterate on the rows returned by SQL
     // $row is an array here
     // I don't know your database model and relation between your 2 tables
     // It isn't a good practice doing sql query while iterating
    // For example with scalar values
    $formId  = $row['formID'];
    $some    = $row['some'];
    $other   = $row['other']; 
    $field   = $row['field'];
    $array[] = $row; 

    // Insert the line
    $insertQuery   = 'INSERT INTO yourothertable(formIdColumnOtherTable, some, other, field) VALUES($formId, $some, $other, $field)';
    $statement     = mysqli_prepare($insertQuery);
    $successInsert = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
}
mysqli_close($con);
...
$data['details'] = $array;
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

For a more adapted answer please give me your two tables definition

I hope it help ! :)